# how to access a variable from outside a function/instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, instance

I have this very simple JavaScript code that should return a Fullname using parameters `firstname` and `lastname` All works fine when I alert out the fullname within the function. But I'm struggling how to make the `fullname` variable accessible from outside the function/instance?

here's my code:

```
var getName = function () {

    this.name = function (firstname, lastname, success) {
        var fullName = firstname + " " + lastname;
        success(fullName);
    };

};


var test = new getName();

test.name("John", "Smith", function (output) {
    var fullname = output;
    alert(fullname); //this works fine
    return fullname; // I need this variable to be accessed from outside this function
});

var myName = fullname; //I need to create the variable here
alert(myName); //this does not work
```

Here's [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ppbd57f8/)

Thank you very much for your help.

**Edit:** I'm building an iPad app where I'm using cordova and javascript plugins.
One of the plugin gives me access to the file inside the device. Now, I need to be able to get the path and use it outside the callback so that I can use anywhere in the scope:

Here's the plugin code:

```
var FileManager = function(){

this.get_path = function(todir,tofilename, success){
        fail = (typeof fail == 'undefined')? Log('FileManager','read file fail'): fail;
        this.load_file(
            todir,
            tofilename,
            function(fileEntry){

                var sPath = fileEntry.toURL();
                success(sPath);
            },
            Log('fail')
        );

    }


    this.load_file = function(dir, file, success, fail, dont_repeat){
        if(!dir || dir =='')
        {
            Log('error','msg')('No file should be created, without a folder, to prevent a mess');
            fail();
            return;
        }
        fail = (typeof fail == 'undefined')? Log('FileManager','load file fail'): fail;
        var full_file_path = dir+'/'+file;
        var object = this;
        // get fileSystem
        fileSystemSingleton.load(
            function(fs){
                var dont_repeat_inner = dont_repeat;
                // get file handler
                console.log(fs.root);
                fs.root.getFile(
                    full_file_path,
                    {create: true, exclusive: false},
                    success,

                    function(error){

                        if(dont_repeat == true){
                            Log('FileManager','error')('recurring error, gettingout of here!');
                            return;
                        }
                        // if target folder does not exist, create it
                        if(error.code == 3){
                            Log('FileManager','msg')('folder does not exist, creating it');
                            var a = new DirManager();
                            a.create_r(
                                dir,
                                function(){
                                    Log('FileManager','mesg')('trying to create the file again: '+file);
                                    object.load_file(dir,file,success,fail,true);
                                },
                                fail
                            );
                            return;
                        }
                        fail(error);
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    };
}
```

and here's how I use it:

```
    var b = new FileManager(); // Initialize a File manager

    b.get_path('Documents','data.json',function(path){
        myPath = path;
        console.log(myPath); //this gives me the path of the file in the console, which works fine
        return myPath; //I return the path to be accessed outside
    });

    var filePath = myPath; //here I need to access the path variable
    console.log(filePath)// here, the path is undefined and it does not work

    //Since I'm using angular services to retrieve the data from json, I'd like to pass the filePath
  //this is a fraction of code for retrieving data:
  return $resource('data.json',{}, {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false}});

  //passing the value does not work
  return $resource(filePath,{}, {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false}});

  //even wrapping resource around instance does not work, it breaks the whole app
  b.get_path('Documents','data.json',function(path){
        myPath = path;
        console.log(myPath); //this gives me the path of the file in the console, which works fine
        return $resource(myPath,{}, {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false}});
    });
```

Factory services:

```
'use strict';
angular
    .module ('myApp')
    .factory('getMeData', function ($resource) {
        var b = new FileManager(); // Initialize a File manager
        b.get_path('Documents','data.json',function(path){
            myPath = path;
            return myPath;
        });

        //below doesn't work when passing path (it is undefined)
        return $resource(myPath,{}, {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false}});

        //when wrapping it around, the app crashes
        b.get_path('Documents','data.json',function(path){
            myPath = path;
            return $resource(myPath,{}, {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false}});
        });

        //none of the solution above work

    });
```

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Agreed however I assume this is more about learning how callbacks work.

Comment: Is this meant to be a test of an async operation? *If not* the code is overkill and straight functions will do. If it is meant async, then the selected answer *will not work* in an async operation.

Comment: Yes, this should be an async operation

Comment: Can you show the entire function as you are attempting to return the result of `$resource()` but the containing function is not shown? The solution will be to introduce a callback at the highest level, but I need to see it all. Thanks.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I have added the services function

Comment: I will need to see the existing code that uses `getMeData` to provide an appropriate example on the calling, but I have updated my answer to match how *I think* it should be done (I do not use Angular).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the `name` function return the result of `success` then you can use the return from the method.

I.e.

```
var getName = function () {
    this.name = function (firstname, lastname, success) {
        var fullName = firstname + " " + lastname;
        return success(fullName);
    };

};


var test = new getName();

var myName = test.name("John", "Smith", function (output) {
    var fullname = output;
    alert(fullname); //this works fine
    return fullname; // I need this variable to be accessed from outside this function
});
alert(myName);
```

Comment: If the question is indeed an async one (as suggested), this answer is returning a value from within an async callback which is a complete no-no and will not work. Make the `getName` function an async operation (as bestmike007 did) and you will see that it fails.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie None of the functions are called Asynchronously when `success(fullName)` is called the  name function will wait for that to complete. I agree that this isn't the kind of code you would see in production (at least hopefully not!) but it will work. See http://jsfiddle.net/opczeuqw/

Comment: If you check the new OP comments, you will see the operation *is* meant to be async: If I change your example to be async it fails: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/opczeuqw/1/

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie  Ah, my apologies, I misunderstood what you were saying. Yes, changing OPs example to use async calls will break the above.

Comment: Please note the OP has now updated the question with an example of the real *async* code used.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie My answer is definitely wrong in that case. Deleting. Edit: No I'm not, can't delete an accepted answer. I'll delete if/when it's unaccepted.

Answer (score 1):

Define `fullname` outside the callback.

```
var getName = function () {

    this.name = function (firstname, lastname, success) {
        var fullName = firstname + " " + lastname;
        success(fullName);
    };

};


var test = new getName();
var fullname;
test.name("John", "Smith", function (output) {
    fullname = output;
    alert(fullname); //this works fine
    return fullname; // I need this variable to be accessed from outside this function
});

alert(fullname);
```

Hope it helps. [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/7ub7mzkq/)

Comment: @angular_learner might have met some async problems. Use [Promise](https://www.promisejs.org/) to avoid bad smell.

Comment: Think it as an async call to a webservice. e.g. [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/y1m36w9p/)

Comment: Indeed: comments removed. Promises *would* make more sense for this code. The selected answer must have friends here, as that still has code smells :)

Comment: This answer has the same problem as Jim's. If it is indeed an async example, then you are alerting fullname long before the value is set by the async callback. Your later JSFiddle is better, but the answer shown is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

**If async required:**

Assuming the actual source of the code is an async one, now confirmed from your comment, you should simply process the result within the callback. The value is simply not available outside of the callback as the result arrives later.

The answers by @Jim and @bestmike007 will not work with an async operation as it returns a value from inside a callback which may occur long after the function is run. (note: @bestmike007 does have an improved answer linked in a comment).

e.g. Look at what happens here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/y1m36w9p/1/ or here http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/opczeuqw/1/

The only way to work with async code is in an async manner. That means you can only handle the result inside the callback:

```
// Get the fullname asyc and process the result
test.name("John", "Smith", function (fullname) {
    alert(fullname); // you can only work with the result in here
});
```

An alternative is to return a jQuery `promise` from `getName.name()`, but the end result will still be a callback to do the work, but this time it would look like this:

```
test.name("John", "Smith").done(function(fullname){
    alert(fullname); // you can only work with the result in here
});
```

but this is more code and complication for no extra benefit at this time.

**For your specific updated example code:**

I am not familiar enough with Angular to confirm this, and would need to see how `getMeData` is called, but you should use another callback as a parameter to the `getMeData` function you register:

```
'use strict';
angular
    .module ('myApp')
    .factory('getMeData', function ($resource, callback) {
        var b = new FileManager(); // Initialize a File manager
        b.get_path('Documents','data.json',function(path){
            callback($resource(path,{}, {'query': {method: 'GET', isArray: false}}));
        });
    });
```

---

**If async *not* required** (obsolete option)

If (as a previous contradictory comment below said) this was not mean to to be async, then do not use callbacks at all, just simple functions/methods returning values: http://fiddle.jshell.net/y1m36w9p/2/

e.g.

```
var getName = function () {
    this.name = function (firstname, lastname) {
        return firstname + " " + lastname;
    };
};

// Create a instance of the getName class
var test = new getName();

// Get the fullname asyc and process the result
var fullname = test.name("John", "Smith");

// Do what you like with the value returned from the function
alert(fullname);
```

Comment: Fantastic explanation. However, I apologize for saying this is an async operation. I need to handle the result outside the callback though :(

Comment: That makes more sense now. `get_path` is very much an async operation. You simply cannot use the value it fetches outside of a callback as *it will not exist yet*. You cannot return values from async callbacks like that. Please refer back to the first part of my answer as it is the correct option.

Comment: Oh no :( the setTimeout will not be very handy though. Is there a no way at all to make it work the way I need it?

Comment: If you mean in my example, the `setTimeout` was only there to emulate a load delay like you would see in practice. You need to show what you wish to do with the `file_path` value, so that I can complete the example. It all depends on what you want to do next :)